# Remove all borders expect bottom using css

Tags: html, css

I have removed all borders except the bottom from my text input field. But when I start to write on the field, it appears again. How to solve it?

```css
input {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 39px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(137, 43, 226, 0.562);
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder='Enter email' required /> <br />
<input type="password" placeholder='Enter password' required /> <br />
```

Comment: that's the ``:focus`` state of the input, not the normal state. So you need to override the focus state too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see when you enter the input field is not the border, but the outline. See the required adjustment below to avoid seeing the outline.

```css
input {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 25%;
  height: 39px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(137, 43, 226, 0.562);
  border-top: 0;
  border-right: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  /* Added */
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder='Enter email' required /> <br />
<input type="password" placeholder='Enter password' required /> <br />
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need change the border on focus:

```
input:focus {
    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 25%;
    height: 39px;
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(137, 43, 226, 0.562);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your CSS with the below code and it works for you.

```
    input,
    input:focus,
    textarea:focus,
    select:focus {
       margin-top: 10px;
       width: 25%;
       height: 39px;
       border: 2px solid rgba(137, 43, 226, 0.562);
       border-top: 0px;
       border-right: 0px;
       border-left: 0px;
       outline: none;
    }
```